# Application unpublished after some time again publish that time my app not display on play store?

Tags: google-play, google-developers-console, google-console-developer

I tried to unpublished my application from play store after some time again i published my application but on that time application not found on that given packagename using search, while in details i found, how to solved this.

Answer (score 0):

Try contacting Google as they would know more about how to fix this than we do. You can use this [link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/publishing) to contact Google about publishing issues.

Hope this helps!